# Custom UIAlertView title only works for alert, not for confim dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(id)frame {    
    NSLog(@"javascript alert : %@",message);    
    UIAlertView* customAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"확인" otherButtonTitles:nil];    
    [customAlert show];  
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)sender runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:(nonnull NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(nonnull WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler{    
    UIAlertView* customAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"확인" otherButtonTitles:@"취소", nil];   
    [customAlert show];
    return true;
}
```

I want to change title of UIAlertView when javascript alert or confirm
dialog pops up.

javascript alert seems works fine but when use javascript confirm dialog,

that dialog does not shows custom title as supposed to do.

can you guys suggest any idea why? any help will be very appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: UIAlertView was deprecated in iOS 8. You should use UIAlertController instead.

Answer (score 0):

wrong implementation. should delete this question but dont know how.

.h file

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(id)frame;
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(id)frame;
```

.m file

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(id)frame {        
    UIAlertView *confirmDiag = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"예", @"예") otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"아니오", @"아니오"), nil];

    [confirmDiag show];
    while (confirmDiag.hidden == NO && confirmDiag.superview != nil) {            
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01f]];
    }

    return diagStat;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(id)frame {
    NSLog(@"javascript alert : %@",message);
    UIAlertView* customAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"확인" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [customAlert show];

}
```